# Validate at client to accept only numbers between 1 to 100 in a textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

Validate at client to accept only numbers in a gridview textbox using JavaScript.

I have a gridview with two labels and one textbox. all I want is user should enter the textbox value 1-100. how can I do this in ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0):

//Html

```
<input type="text" name="textboxId" id="textboxId"/>
```

//Javascript

```
var val = document.getElementById('textboxId').value;
if(val < 1 || val > 100){
alert('Value must be between 1 and 100');
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you want to support, you might not need to write any JavaScript. HTML5 added some new input types including [type=number](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number) which supports min and max attributes.

Support is [patchy](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) at the moment, but maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could add the onkeydown and validate the input. If you dont want it, return false;

```
node.onkeydown = function(a_event)
{
   // validate non number input
   if ((a_event.keyCode >= 65 && a_event.keyCode <= 90))
      return false;                                 
};
```

In addition you can parseInt the input and return false as well

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the `onchange` event?

Comment: That would allow letters as input since onchange fires after tabout

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Num" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ForeColor="DarkOrange" ValidationExpression="^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$" ControlToValidate="Num" runat="server" ErrorMessage="accept only numbers between 1 to 100"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```